# How to make a transparent navigation bar using SwiftUI in iOS 16?

Tags: swiftui

In iOS 16, there are now new SwiftUI modifiers for adjusting navigation bars.

The following:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 200)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .navigationTitle("Hello")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

                // New modifiers
                .toolbarBackground(.clear, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

[image]

Notice there is an translucent effect applied.

Does anyone know how to remove this translucent effect and instead make it transparent **whilst keeping dark color scheme** (title/status bar is white)?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this could work for you:

```
.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar
```

> Edit:

You can try:

```
.toolbarColorScheme
```

You can find more information here:
[How to change status bar color in SwiftUI](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-status-bar-color)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I would like to keep the color scheme as dark (title and status bar as white). This does hide the navigation bar but reverts the color scheme to white. I've updated my question with this information.

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe this would do the job